# Trouble creating Custom Completions for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, tab-completion

**UPDATED**

I'm working on Salesforce development using the MavensMate plugin for Sublime Text 3. I'm wanting to create a custom completions file that will contain some common HTML tag class names that I use often in my Visualforce pages.

Visualforce uses normal HTML tags, but also has custom tags that look something like this...

```
<apex:tagName ... />
```

Visualforce pages have a file name extension "filename.page".  MavensMate uses the HTML syntax highlighting, and when I press "ctrl+alt+shift+p" to get the scope selector(s) it shows the same as a normal HTML file would (ie text.html.basic).

I can get my completions file to work in a normal HTML page outside of tags, but not within a class definition in a tag.  I can't seem to get it to work at all in a Visualforce page.

My initial file was based of the documentation found [here](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/completions.html#file-format).

```
{
   "scope": "text.html.basic",

   "completions":
   [
      { "trigger": "test\tTheTest", "contents": "this is a test" }
   ]
}
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to work.  I've tried every permutation of the above scope.  My file is named "test.sublime-completions" and is located in the Packages/User/ directory.  I've tried renaming to HTML.sublime-completions, html.sublime-completions.

I've changed the "auto_complete_selector" and the "auto_complete_triggers" to try and solve this, but still nothing.

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text, string.quoted.double.html",
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": "<",
        "selector": "text.html",
        "selector": "string.quuoted.double.html"
    }
],
```

I made a post on the ST forums found [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21070) but nobody has replied. :(

Can anyone shed some light on to what I'm doing wrong, and how I can get this resolved.

As a work around I can make Snippets for each class, but it seems more appropriate to do this via Completions.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your scope specification is invalid. the following works perfectly fine for me:

```
{
   "scope": "text.html",

   "completions":
   [
      { "trigger": "test\tTheTest", "contents": "this is a test" }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I've switched my scope to match yours, and it is still not working.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, so I got it to work in HTML outside of a tag class definition, but I still can't get it to work inside a class on a tag.  Also I think I have another issue.  I'm going to update my post.